# Uncaught ReferenceError: ModuleA is not defined

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am using following code which uses prototypal inheritance. Somehow when I create a new instance of `ModuleA` then it return

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ModuleA is not defined

Below is my code

```
(function () {
  var ModuleA = function () {
    console.log('ModuleA');
  };

  ModuleA.prototype = (function () {
    var moduleA = function () {

    };

    return {
      moduleA: moduleA
    }
  }());

  return ModuleA;

})();

new ModuleA();
```

**UPDATE**

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xmmyo6pu/)**

Comment: From what I see, ModuleA is declared as local variable within scope of the first anonymous function. You won't have access to it outside.

Comment: ModuleA is declared inside another function so it is limited to the scope of that function and why it is not available outside it.

Comment: I am returning ModuleA constructor at the end of Self invoking function.

Comment: returning it to where? A `return` doesn't move it's scope and would only be returned to a variable that could call that function which is not the case here

Comment: Did my answer work for you then?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you explicitely put your ModuleA declaration in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which will hide everything inside. So ModuleA is in the scope of your IIFE. You *did* return return `ModuleA` but you didn't put it anywhere.

Do this instead :

```
var ModuleA = (function () {
  var ModuleA = function () {
    console.log('ModuleA');
  };

  ModuleA.prototype = (function () {
    var moduleA = function () {

    };

    return {
      moduleA: moduleA
    }
  }());

  return ModuleA;

})();

new ModuleA();
```